# Detecting WCDMA and HSDPA on Android

Tags: android, networking

I've got an app that runs across Android versions 1.6+, and needs to detect the network type.

I've got a problem with HSDPA and WCDMA, though - the former only has a defined constant for TelephonyManager#getNetworkType in API version 5+, and the latter doesn't seem to have one at all.

Does anyone know what a phone on these network types will return for TelephonyManager#getNetworkType before and after Android 2.0? (I'm assuming that on 2.0+ on an HSDPA network it'll return the appropriate constant, but the rest appear undefined...)

Comment: Do you specifically need to know what values will be returned for those networks, or is this part of a bigger problem (e.g. detecting 3G vs 2G)?

Comment: Both. :) For the bigger problem I've gone with assuming it's 3G if it's not 2G, WiFi or no connection. But it would still be nice to know what gets returned when we *are* on these network types...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the source code for the [TelephonyManager class in Android 1.6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java), the return value for HSPDA and WCDMA should be `NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN` (0).

If you look at the constants defined in the [Telephony Manager class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) for the various network types, you can see when each network type was introduced to the API:

HSPDA: API version 5+
WCDMA: (Not documented)

Based on what I have read in wikipedia on [WCDMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Speed_Packet_Access), it also goes by the name UMTS, which means that a WCDMA phone will return `NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS` (3).

**Summary**

HSPDA:

- returns `NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN` (0) in API Version 4 (Android <= 1.6)
- returns `NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA` (8) in API Version 5+ (Android 2.0+)

WCDMA:

- returns `NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS` (3) since API Version 1

**EDIT**

I should also point out that, since Android is open source, its possible that the handset provider has overridden these values and functions, so it is possible that they may deviate from the trunk version.